# Why pythons open function throw exception if file not exist only when i use os.sep inside filename?

Tags: python, file, built-in

This works fine:

```
file1 = open("not_exisiting_file1.txt", "w")
```

but this not:

```
file2 = open("folder" + os.sep + "not_exisiting_file2.txt", "w")
```

Why?

Comment: Does "folder" exist? What happens if you try opening "folder/not_existing_file1.txt"?

Comment: Its working fine for me. Check if your folder exists or not.

Comment: Folder not exist. I thought python will do it for my like with not existing files. :) (and with "folder/not_existing_file1.txt" it does not work too)

Comment: Sorry, Python's `open` won't implicitly create missing directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely answer I can imagine without knowing more about your situation is that the folder "folder" does not exist.  This has nothing to do with os.sep.

Try this:

```
import os, os.path
folder = 'folder'
os.makedirs(folder)
with open(os.path.join(folder, 'file1.txt'), 'w') as f:
  f.write('now my folder and file both exist!')
```

Comment: Yep, "folder" does not exist, i though pythons "open" function will make new folder for me like it do with not existing files. :)